# What is the difference between Windows Store app, W. Phone app and W. Phone Silverlight app

Tags: store

I am new to this environment but I got confused a bit, when I see these 3 kind of apps.
I assumes that Windows Store App is an app that goes on the market place, but also the WP app does that ... and what about Windows Phone Silverlight?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but it's a dev question and it's not allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there is the "Windows Phone Store" containing "Windows Phone Apps" and the "Windows Store" containing "Windows (8.1) Apps" for tablets, notebooks etc.

The term Windows Phone Silverlight App only describes the "framework" app developers can use to create apps for Windows Phone. There are also apps written in HTML/JavaScript and those based on WinRt. The consumer however doesn't really need to know or care about this as you won't see a difference when those are available in the store.

The only thing interesting here is that apps can also be "universal" which means they are available both in the Windows and Windows Phone store and can be downloaded in one of them for free if you bought them on the other platform.